# Error running Spring boot tests in IntelliJ Community 2017.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, junit

This is a very weird behavior. I have a Spring boot application which works fine. Since a couple of days (I just switched the app to another Git repo, if it means something) every time I run tests with IntelliJ I gest the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to add
>   PropertySource to Environment     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.addPropertiesFilesToEnvironment(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:198)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>     ... 24 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [com/mycompany/myproject/test.properties] cannot be opened because it
>   does not exist    at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.(ResourcePropertySource.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils.addPropertiesFilesToEnvironment(TestPropertySourceUtils.java:194)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted 09:54:42.723 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener
>   - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@371a67ec testClass = AudioVideoControllerTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null],
>   testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5ed828d testClass =
>   AudioVideoControllerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   com.mycompany.myproject.myprojectApplication}',
>   contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}',
>   propertySourceLocations =
>   '{classpath:/com/mycompany/myproject/test.properties}',
>   propertySourceProperties =
>   '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}',
>   contextCustomizers =
>   set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@548e7350,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@77cd7a0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@754ba872,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13805618],
>   resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with
>   mode [null]. Process finished with exit code -1

So it says it can't find the test.properties file I declare here:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class AudioVideoControllerTest {...}
```

The file is in the classpath (src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/test.properties)

Now the weirdest part. If I open the project with Eclipse (Sprig Tool Suite actually) and I run tests, they work. Then I run again tests on IntelliJ and... they work!

So it looks like Eclipse/STS makes some changes when I open and refresh the project but I wonder what it is.

Comment: The file must be in `src/main/resources` not `src/main/java`, this applies to all non java resources.

Comment: If the file is dedicated to tests, it should be in `src/test/resources`. You can also try to change the location value with `classpath:test.properties`. [Check this for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-property-sources).

Comment: If I move the file away from `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject` it doesn't work anymore. I guess because it keeps prepending `src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject` as prefix. For example, I moved `test.properties` in `src/main/resources` and I get the error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/mycompany/myproject/test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`. Adding `classpath:` doesn't help either.

Comment: I nowhere mentioned you should change the package/directory it is in. I only specified you should have a different base location (as dictated by Maven). You should still put it in the same directory structure.

Comment: I just used the default layout proposed by STS when I created the project http://www.screencast.com/t/SAqpfc4A so you say I should move the resources folder inside src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject ?

Comment: However, every time I mess up with IntelliJ (by moving around the test.properties file) I can fix it simply by running tests from STS with propert file under src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject. Running tests from STS fixes tests in IntelliJ :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is dragging the test.properties file to another folder, let IntelliJ update references and then move again the test.properties file back into the root folder and, again, let IntelliJ update all references.